# Create a group DM Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my bot to message two people but in the same chat window (like when you add a friend to a conversation). The only thing I've found is how to send to a single person by doing `<client>.send(message);` How could I add a second person to that conversation?

Any examples would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discord.js doesn't really implement that because in Discord bots can't join Group DMs. You would need a self-bot (a bot that runs on a user account), but Discord doesn't want them to be used, so discord.js didn't make this options.

Therefore, at the moment there's no way to do that: the groupDMChannel class can't be used to create them, and since there's no method to do that from the client or from a DM channel I think you're stuck there :\

Answer (score 2):

just taking a quick look at the Discord.js documentation, it seems they do have a `GroupDMChannel` class, and this seems to be what you want / need to use.

The two methods that stand out to me:

- [send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GroupDMChannel?scrollTo=send)
- [addUser](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GroupDMChannel?scrollTo=addUser)

Where I'm *assuming* (I know I shouldn't!) that you have to call `addUser` first.

disclaimer: not going into detail, since I don't have experience using this particular module

Comment: I am blind lol, thanks for answering so quickly. I could have sworn I ctrl+f'd group.

Comment: Any idea how to use it? I cannot instantiate it when I try to use new GroupDMChannel(client, data); Can't find any other examples. I tried looking for something like a client.createDM(); to get a reference to it but I can't.

Comment: I tried to whip up a small example (+ get some actual experience with the API / module)... but alas, so far I haven't managed to create a groupDMChannel yet! (did manange to create a normal channel though...). Either I'm tired and can't see it in the documentation (or maybe it's a relatively new feature?, and not that well documented in the discord.js module!). An example would go a long way here though!

Comment: I did find a way doing client.createGroupDM(client, data) but it always errors out, even if given the proper values. Oh well ty anyways

Comment: FYI, you still can't create the group dm which is the purpose of the original question. I think you can only add users to an existing dm. Regardless, kind of odd that you can't do this but oh well.